# Using rvest to login on web

Tags: r, forms, authentication, rvest

I tried to login to this page but I get this error:

**Error: Unknown field names: customer[email], customer[password]**

My code it's:

```
library(XLConnect)
library(rvest)
{
 {
 #Address of the login webpage
 url <-"https://www.silversanz.com/es/account/login"
 }
 #create a web session with the desired login address
 pgsession<-html_session(url)
 pgform<-html_form(pgsession)
 filled_form<-set_values(pgform, 
                      'customer[email]'="mymail",
                      'customer[password]'="mypass"
                      )
 {
 url<-("https://www.silversanz.com/mi-cuenta/pedidos")
 }
 dades<-read_html(url)

 date<-dades %>% html_nodes("dd") %>% html_attr("order__date")
 total<-dades %>% html_nodes("dd") %>% html_attr("order__total")
 state<-dades %>% html_nodes("dd") %>% html_attr("order__state")

 info<-as.data.frame(cbind(date,state,total))
 info<-info[!is.na(info$id),]
 info<-info[!duplicated(info),]

 writeWorksheetToFile(file="C:/Users/...",
                   data=info,
                   sheet="item",
                   clearSheets=TRUE
                   )
}
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three forms on the webpage. You can see that when you access `pgform`. Therefore you have to specify the one you want to use. I assume, you want to login, which is the first one:

```
filled_form<-set_values(pgform[[1]], 
                      'customer[email]'="mymail",
                      'customer[password]'="mypass")
```

Comment: Done! Thank you :-)